# Load data into hive table from CSV containing dictionary

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I've a CSV file and Im trying to put it in a hive table.
The CSV contains dictionary for some columns.

The file looks like this :

`a,b,{'c':'d','e':'f'},g`

So the table should look like :

```
| col1     | col2           | col3              | col4|
| -------- | -------------- | ----              | --- |
| a        | c              | {'c':'d','e':'f'} |   g |
```

But it picks up the comma inside parenthesis.

How do I ignore the comma inside the parenthesis.

Im using this to write the hive table.

```
create external table mytable(
  col1 string,
  col2 string,
  col3 string,
  col4 string
) 

row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile location '/user/myuser/mydir/';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can enclose your columns with double quotes, you can use  OpenCSVSerde to load data correctly. Most csv generation facility should be able to do this.

Your file should look like below-

```
"a","b","{'c':'d','e':'f'}","g"
```

your script should be like this -

```
   col1    STRING, 
   col2    STRING, 
   col3    STRING, 
   col4    STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "\t",
   "quoteChar"     = "\""
)  
LOCATION '/your/folder/location/';
```

You can check this linke https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde. Now, this process will work perfectly for string columns, for other data type, you need to convert them in next step.